# While drop database through ef core anExtention Hoisting Error error occured

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, migration

I am adding data Identity Entity Framework core in my .Net Core Application. I have installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore in my Application and while trying to drop the database I am getting an error

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ISystemClock' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[Domain.AppUser]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ISystemClock' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[Domain.AppUser]'.)
> Unable to create an object of type 'DataContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

My DataContext Class is

```
using System;
using Domain;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Persistence
{
    public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    {
          public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
          {
          }

          public DbSet<Value> Values { get; set; }
          public DbSet<Activity> Acitivities {get;set;}

          protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
          {

            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
          }
    }
}
```

and my Startup.cs Class is

```
using API.Middleware;
using Application.Activities;
using Domain;
using FluentValidation.AspNetCore;
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Persistence;

namespace API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt => {
                opt.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
                    .AddFluentValidation(cfg => cfg.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Create>());


            var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>();
            var identityBuilder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, builder.Services);
            identityBuilder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();
            identityBuilder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
            
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            // app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            }); 
        }
    }
}
```

and my AppUser.cs Class is

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Domain
{
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I guess you missed default token provider for Identity. var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

Answer (score 0):

I Just Added `services.TryAddSingleton<ISystemClock, SystemClock>();`  before `var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>();` it wokred fine